# Creating a WinDbg-readable dump of QEmu guest OS

Tags: windows, windbg, dump, qemu, crash-dumps

I am running QEmu on Linux and the virtualized OS is Windows XP. I would like to have either the 1st or the 2nd possibility:

1. to apply a command in QEmu which creates a dump that can be opened with WinDbg
2. to apply a command in QEmu which creates a dump of a particular type and then use another utility to make it readable with WinDbg

I know about QEmu's "dump-guest-memory" (creates an ELF-dump), rekall's `raw2dmp` plugin and Volatility's `raw2dmp` plugin. The output can be scanned by WinDbg, but in fact you face the problem of a bad header - probably, the most important part of a dump, which is good for nothing when the dump was created using tools/plugins mentioned above. Many fields are lacking in correct details. Comparing to a normal dump created by Windows OS itself (for example, when crashing), which contains information which is full and correct.

I am a student and I got the task to resolve this problem. I think it is reasonable to ensure that it has not been completed yet by anybody so doing it does make sense.

Comment: http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/kernel-debugging-qemu-windbg/?

Comment: @ThomasWeller well, thanks, but that's a bit different. I'm interested exactly in dumps. And I forgot to mention that the host OS is Linux.

Comment: cant you run two qemu instances both with windows on this linux  use one qemu as host and other as target initiate a kd connection between them and use the .crash command or .dump command to get a dump ? or do i misunderstand your query ?

Answer (score 1):

if Qemu Monitor commands are acceptable set the `crashonctrlscroll` registry key in the guest os

set the dump creation parameters in SystemApplet

```
Mycomputer->properties->Advanced->Startup and Recovery->Settings->Complete memory dump)
path , no overwrite , uncheck automatically restart
```

and from Qemu monitor shell use `sendkeys ctrl_r-scroll_lock-scroll_lock`

that will generate a dump that will be windbg compatible

```
manually initiated_crash bugcheck code 0xe2
```

screen shot of a 700 mb ram xp64 guest os running inside qemu on a 32 bit xp32 os 
[image]

Comment: yes, this is a simple case whereas we can manually cause the creation of an original dump, which will be absolutely correct and normal. But the goal is to devise a method of getting a normal dump in abnormal situations when the guest OS can't provide us  with such a dump. So, in this cases we can use only qemu's commands (and subsequenly, if needed, other tools to process qemu's output).

Comment: wishing you good luck finding official dump header and format details / documentation afaik ms never released such details last time i checked the only available methods were to reverse engineer dumpchk in windbg  and correlate  i probably have code in some damned flash drive in an attic that simulates dumpchk using dbghelp / dbgeng functions  ping back if you want them ill try to locate them andreas schuster (forensikxxxx.de) had two posts detailing mdmp and du64 headers google

Comment: thanks, but you shouldn't do it, I have already started researching :) Just tried to find out if the problem is resolved (or almost resolved) already.

Comment: ok best of luck btw qemu also can send an nmi and crash dumps can also be generated with nmi (i never got it to  work coz qemu windows were all somehow broken /unusable for windows (only kazus version < 0.9 were ok) during the period i played with them around 9 10 years back